# How to remove unicode characters from database in Django

Tags: django, elasticsearch, unicode

i am new to Django and i have built quite huge database. now i am going to implement elastic search. but when i run **push-to-index file** it gives me error like this,

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError('ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 916: ordinal not in range(128)) caused by: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 916: ordinal not in range(128))
```

can anybody tell me how can i remove all Unicode ASCII characters from my database. is there any script which i can run in views? please help in this regard. any help or suggestion will be highly appriciated
Thanks.